# XamarinBranchAndroid: MainActivity to BranchActivity results in a blank screen

Tags: android, xamarin, branch.io

So, we have this existing App with a MainActivity, with whole bunch of interface implementations. I want to implement IBranchSessionInterface. I have followed the documentation as given here: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/xamarin/
Have BranchActivity and BranchErrorActivity

One thing I can't seem to understand in the following sequence:

1. ApplicationClass calls:

   BranchAndroid.GetAutoInstance(this.ApplicationContext);
2. MainActivity that Implements IBranchSessionInterface has this code in OnCreate()

   `BranchAndroid.Init(this, Resources.GetString(Resource.String.branch_key), this);`
3. When the Branchsession is successfully initiated, it calls the IBranchSessionInterface, InitSessionComplete callback. 
   Here is the full method impl:

   ```
   public void InitSessionComplete(Dictionary<string, object> data)
   {
       var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(BranchActivity));
       intent.PutExtra("BranchData", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));

       StartActivity(intent);
   }
   ```

After this, what needs to happen? Because after Starting branch activity I see nothing but empty screen. How is it suppose to come back to MainActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Branch activity is simply an example of how you can use Branch link data. You don't actually need that activity, or the intent to redirect to it.
You may simply delete all of that code and replace it with the following to view the data upon app open:

```
public void InitSessionComplete(Dictionary<string, object> data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Branch Link Data: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));

        }
```

Comment: it would be helpful if this information was attached to the actual docs.